# Adding Images that are located on a website to a listview on c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am wondering if it is possible to add some images from a website like:

http://www.website.com/892374_838.jpg
  http://www.website.com/2324374_838.jpg
  http://www.website.com/23431_838.jpg

to a listview in c# dynamically.

Comment: yes, its possible and is that answer to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a listview control with name listView1, the following will do it for you:

```
    private void PopulateListView()
    {
        ImageList images = new ImageList();
        images.Images.Add(
            LoadImage("http://www.website.com/892374_838.jpg"));
        images.Images.Add(
            LoadImage("http://www.website.com/23431_838.jpg"));

        listView1.SmallImageList = images;
        listView1.Items.Add("An item", 0);
        listView1.Items.Add("Another item item", 1);
    }

    private Image LoadImage(string url)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request =
            System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream responseStream =
            response.GetResponseStream();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(responseStream);

        responseStream.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
string imageUrl = "";
// Create the requests.
WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();
Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());

// save image
webImage.Save("C:\\image.jpg");

ImageList imgList;
imgList.Images.Add(webImage);
ListView1.LargeImageList = imgList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the type of the project, are you talking about Windows Forms, WPF...?

If Windows Forms, you should first use a WebClient, get the stream of the image, and then make an Image.FromStream().

If WPF you can do it, by simply setting the Image Source property to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a Roman approach : Divide and Conquer.

You should split the problem in 2 or 3 parts. First, how to retrieve an image from an URL.
Second (optional), store the image locally, if you have to load it multiple times, etc.. Third, display the image. Also, I really don't think all these steps should be implemented in the UI layer of your application.

Should you want to read more on the Separation of Concerns, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is your friend!